# Empty array before loading new content in component angular SPA

Tags: javascript, angular, http

The image content is loading from my API, but when i click and change HTML data, the content is still displayed on the page for maybe 1 second, before the other content is loaded. I tried to fix that with ngOnChanges(), but it doesnt seem to work. Is there a clever way, to empty the data instantly upon clicking the new tab, and then loading the new data, without the user still seeing the old content (and the new content header for that matter)?

Component:

```
export class DiscoverComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any[] = [];
  stories: any;

  page: string = '0';
  feed: any;
  hits: any = '6';

  notLoaded: boolean = false;

  constructor(private storiesService: StoriesService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.router);
    this.feed = this.route.snapshot.params['feed'];

    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.feed = params['feed'];
      }
    );

    this.getStories();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.data) {
      for (let story in this.data) {
        this.data = [];
      }
      this.getStories();
    }
  }

  getStories() {
    this.storiesService.getData(this.page, this.hits, this.feed)
      .subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("getStories!")
        if (!data) {
          this.notLoaded = true;
        } else {
          for (let story in data) {
            this.data = data;
          }
        }
      })
  }

  getCuratedFeed() {
    this.page = '0';
    this.hits = '6';
    this.feed = 'curated';
    this.getStories();
    console.log("Curated!")
  }

  getTrendingFeed() {
    this.page = '0';
    this.hits = '6';
    this.feed = 'trending';
    this.getStories();
    console.log("trending")
  }

  getlatestFeed() {
    this.page = '0';
    this.hits = '6';
    this.feed = 'latest';
    this.getStories();
    console.log("latest!")
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<app-top-nav></app-top-nav>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <li class="navbar-right"><a routerLink="/discover/curated" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="getCuratedFeed()">Curated</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-right"><a routerLink="/discover/trending" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="getTrendingFeed()">Trending</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-right"><a routerLink="/discover/latest" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="getlatestFeed()">Latest</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-right"><a routerLink="/map" routerLinkAcive="active">Map</a></li>
  </div>
</nav>

<h1>DiscoverComponent</h1>
<div>
  <h2> {{this.feed}} </h2>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <ng-container *ngIf="!notLoaded">
    <div class="col-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12" *ngFor="let story of data.hits">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img *ngIf="story.storyMediaType === 'image'" class="img-fluid" src="{{story.storyThumbnailImage}}" />
        <img *ngIf="story.storyMediaType === 'video'" class="img-fluid" src="{{story.storyThumbnailImage}}" width="150" height="94" />
        <div class="caption">
          <p>{{story.storyCity}}, {{story.storyCountry}}</p>
          <h3>{{story.storyHeadline}}</h3>
          <p>Uploadet {{story.uploadDate}}</p>
          <p>Bruger: {{story.userDisplayName}}</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Like</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>

<hr>

<div infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="1000" (scrolled)="onScroll()">

</div>

<div class="notification is-warning" *ngIf="finished">
  <p>Ikke mere materiale!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried by setting this.data=[] in getCuratedFeed , getLatestFeed and getTrendingFeed method.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much. 1up for you, sir.